# Unrecognized option --conf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm triggering a spark job in EMR using spark-submit in client deploy mode. This is my spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client \
             --num-executors 3 \
             --executor-cores 4 \
             --executor-memory 10000m \
             --driver-memory 2g \
             --conf "spark.archives=s3://spark/venv.tar.gz#environment" \
             --conf "spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python" \
             --conf "spark.pyspark.python=./environment/bin/python" \
             --conf "jars.packages=io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0" \
             --conf "sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
             --conf "sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" \
             s3://spark/count_numbers.py \
             --source-directory s3://data-in/words/ \
             --output-directory s3://data-out/word-count/
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
Error: Unrecognized option: --conf "spark.archives
```

I tried so many things at this point, thankful for any help I can get

Comment: my guess is some quoting issue, when something reads your command and passes it on to something else to execute. Tried 1) using single quotes? 2) putting everything on a single line (removing `\` at end)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have additional --source-directory ....... etc after your python main file. After the python file should be the application arguments

Comment: It's the argument to the python file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. In the end I was calling `spark-submit` correctly. I submitted the job using airflow and the EMR operator expect you to pass in an array of arguments, I passed in a string of arguments. They look identical when calling `spark-submit` so it took quite some hair-pulling and teeth grinding to figure it out.